# Logging out and back in clears "Your Sites"

Tags: discussion, bug, android-app

App version: 1.0.35
Device: Nexus 7
Problem: When I logout of the app and then log back in, the list of `Your Sites` get reset, but they are restored if you click on the `Edit` option in the sidebar.

Logged in
[image]

After logging out then back in.

[image]

P.S. Should Meta SE be displayed as `Meta` on that sidebar?